# Tab View throws Exception

Tags: android, tabview

In Androd_Tab_view.java file, I have the following  code :

tabs = (TabHost)findViewById(R.id.TabHost1);
    tabs.setup();

```
TabHost.TabSpec first_tab = tabs.newTabSpec("tag1");
first_tab.setContent(new Intent(this,FirstTab.class));
first_tab.setIndicator("Book");
tabs.addTab(first_tab);
//SecondTab.class
TabHost.TabSpec second_tab = tabs.newTabSpec("tag2");
second_tab.setContent(new Intent(this,SecondTab.class));
second_tab.setIndicator("Authors");
tabs.addTab(second_tab);
```

In FirstTab.java file I have the following code :

```
public class FirstTab extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

/* First Tab Content */
        TextView textView = new TextView(this); 
        textView.setText("First Tab");
        setContentView(textView);

    }
}
```

In SecondTab.java file I have the following code :

```
     public class SecondTab extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  /* Second Tab Content */

        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setText("Second Tab"); 
        setContentView(textView);

    }
}
```

But when I try to run this code I get an exception . What can be possible solution for this problem ??

Comment: Please post the logcat.  It will get to the problem quickly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create Tab like this

```
   void tabCreation() {

    tabHost.setup();

    TabSpec spec1 = tabHost.newTabSpec("Accounts");
    spec1.setIndicator(createTabView(tabHost.getContext(), "Accounts", R.drawable.tab_home));
    Intent inte = new Intent(TabsActivity.this,  Activityone.class);
    inte.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    spec1.setContent(inte);
    // spec1.setContent(R.id.tab1);

    TabSpec spec2 = tabHost.newTabSpec("Contacts");
    spec2.setIndicator(createTabView(tabHost.getContext(), "Contacts", R.drawable.tab_account));
    Intent _int = new Intent(TabsActivity.this,  Activitytwo.class);
    _int.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    spec2.setContent(_int);
    // /spec2.setContent(R.id.tab2);

    TabSpec spec3 = tabHost.newTabSpec("Chats");         

    tabHost.addTab(spec1);
    tabHost.addTab(spec2);       

    tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
}

private static View createTabView(final Context context, final String text, final int id) {

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.tab_indicator, null);
    TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
    tv.setText(text);
    ImageView icon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.icon);
    icon.setImageResource(id);
    return view;
}
 }
```

and your Activities are

```
 public class FirstTab extends Activity {
  /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_accounts); 


    /* First Tab Content */
       TextView textView = new TextView(this); 
       textView.setText("First Tab");
      setContentView(textView);
```

and

```
  public class secondTab extends Activity {
  /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.contacts_accounts); 


    /* First Tab Content */
       TextView textView = new TextView(this); 
       textView.setText("First Tab");
      setContentView(textView);

    }
}
```

and tis http://www.androidhive.info/2011/08/android-tab-layout-tutorial/

Comment: I cant understand what do you want to mean by "spec1.setIndicator(createTabView(tabHost.getContext(), "Accounts", R.drawable.tab_home));" ?? Can you please explain that ??

Comment: that line indicates we want set image in tab-layout like this http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-tablayout-example/ that is depend ing on  we requirement..

Comment: public class AppleActivity extends Activity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.apple_layout);
        
        TextView textview = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.apple_textView);
        textview.setText("This is Apple tab");
        
    }
}

When I updated the activity of apple as above the text of textview is not shown . Why ??